# Tmux script, open two panes, bind close key

Tags: sh, tmux

I have the following script:

```
#!/bin/sh
tmux new-session -d -s vim 'vim index.js'
tmux split-window -h 'nodemon index.js'
tmux -2 attach-session -d
```

My goal is to have a tmux session open with vim in left pane and [nodemon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon) running in the right. This seems to start up fine, but then stops and the right pane closes after a few seconds.

Additionally I'd like to have it set the cursor in the left pane on start.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that you have bound pane to a command. Which means when you close command the pane will close too. Use different approach. Open pane and then `send-keys` to open desired command

```
#!/bin/sh
tmux new-session -d -s vim 
tmux send-keys -t vim:.1 'vim index.js' Enter
tmux split-window -h 
tmux send-keys -t vim:.2 'nodemon index.js' Enter
# select pane
tmux select-pane -t vim:.2 
tmux -2 attach-session -d
```

**Note:** Also you could look into https://github.com/tmuxinator/tmuxinator

Comment: It's opening the 2 panes now, but I get the following `can't find pane 1vim index.js`, 
`can't find pane 2`

Comment: @Fluidbyte I forgot to put space on second line, after `vim:.1`. Use fixed version

Comment: yeah, I tried that, still getting `can't find pane 1` and `can't find pane 2` (twice)

Comment: it seems to work fine if I use `right` and `left` instead of `vim:.1` and `vim:.2`